# Cuda Summation per block. I get 0 returned to the sums. What is wrong?

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, sum

I tried summation in cuda . I cant find what i did wrong here.
The sum is always returned 0. Can anyone help.

The shared tag defines the variable common in each block.
So i tried to sum one block at a time and finally sum up the result for overall sum.

But the sum doesnt work for block. And i am stuck.
Can anyone help.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cuda.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    //#define BLOCK_SIZE 32         // size of vectors


    __global__ void add( float * i_data, float * sum){
        int tid = blockIdx.x *  blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

         __shared__ float s_data;

        s_data = 0;
// must be synchronized

        __syncthreads();

// reduce and sum

// typical in GPU computings

        for (int i = 0; i<blockDim.x; i++)
        {
            __syncthreads();

            if (tid <= i)

            {
                //s_data[blockIdx.x]+ = s_data[tid] + s_data[i+tid];

                s_data+= i_data[tid];

            }
        }
        if (tid == 0)
            sum[blockIdx.x]=s_data;

    }

    int main()  {
        int T = 10, B = 5;                  // threads per block and blocks per         grid
        float  *a,*b;               // host pointers
        float *dev_a, *dev_b;       // device pointers to host memory
        int sizeIN = T*B*sizeof(int);
        int sizeOUT = B*sizeof(int);

        a= new float[T*B];
        b= new float[B];

        for(int i = 0;i<B;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<T;j++)
            {
                a[i*T+j]=i;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<B;i++)
        {
            b[i]=0;
        }




        cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_a, sizeIN);
        cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_b, sizeOUT);

        cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, sizeIN, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, sizeOUT, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        add<<< B, T >>> (dev_a, dev_b);

        cudaMemcpy(a,dev_a,  sizeIN, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaMemcpy(b,dev_b,  sizeOUT, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        for(int i = 0;i<B;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<T;j++)
            {
                std::cout<< a[i*T+j]<<"\t";
                std::cout<<std::endl;
            }
            std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl<<"sum is: "<<b[i]<<std::endl;
        }



        std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl;

        cudaFree(dev_a);
        cudaFree(dev_b);
        free(a);
        free(b);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong in 2 ways:

```
    if (tid = 0)
```

First, you should be doing a comparison `==` not an assignment `=`.  I don't know why your compiler didn't warn you about this.

Second, `tid` is only zero for one thread in the entire *grid*:

```
    int tid = blockIdx.x *  blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
```

You want one thread in each block to write the block result out to global memory:

```
    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
```

This is also a problem, similarly:

```
        if (tid <= i)
```

This is only satisfied for threads in the first block.  Beyond that, I have to start to guess at what you want.  I guess you're trying to sum the values in each block.  Your construction is not a parallel reduction, but to make the minimum changes to get it "functional" I would rewrite the end of your kernel like this:

```
// reduce and sum

// typical in GPU computings

    for (int i = 0; i<blockDim.x; i++)
    {
        if (threadIdx.x == i)

        {
            //s_data[blockIdx.x]+ = s_data[tid] + s_data[i+tid];

            s_data+= i_data[tid];

        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
        sum[blockIdx.x]=s_data;

}
```

Although you didn't have any CUDA API errors, it's good practice to use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and also run your code with `cuda-memcheck` any time you are having trouble with a cuda code.

I mentioned that your code above is not a classical reduction.  Its just an unoptimal for-loop.

To learn about a CUDA parallel reduction, study the [cuda sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) and the accompanying [presentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf), and there are many examples here on the CUDA tag on SO as well that you can search on.

Comment: exactly, changing the kernel to this worked. Silly mistakes

__global__ void add( float * i_data, float * sum){
 int tid = blockIdx.x *  blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  __shared__ float s_data;

 s_data = 0;
 // must be synchronized

 __syncthreads();

 // reduce and sum

 // typical in GPU computings

 for (int i = 0; i<blockDim.x; i++)
 {
  __syncthreads();

  if (threadIdx.x <= i)

  {
   //s_data[blockIdx.x]+ = s_data[tid] + s_data[i+tid];

   s_data+= i_data[tid];

  }
 }
 if (threadIdx.x == 0)
  sum[blockIdx.x]=s_data;

}